# Ajax form submission always fails

Tags: ajax, forms

```
error: function(results){
            console.log(results);
        }
```

This is the error : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0coT.png

I am not sure how to interpret this, can anyone give me any help?

Comment: Could you explain more and upload more code ?

Comment: The **third** argument to `error` tells you what the error is.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: mohsin azeem, I can't really upload the entire code,was hoping I could get some help just based off of the results logged in console

Answer (score 0):

The property that matters the most based on the image shared, is the `responseText` - that will be a HTML page or fragment, somewhere within will be the detail you need to decipher the reason that the ajax call fell into the `error` block and not the `success` block.

Change your error block to do something like:

`console.log(results.responseText)`

and you will then limit the wall of noise to just the http response the server gave, which will help you debug.